# HD: Reformat - Device or resource busy (udisks-error-quark,0)

Tags: fedora, rhel, filesystems, hard-disk, live-usb

I am trying to reformat a Hard Drive from LiveOS.  I am using the partitioning GUI tool.  I am stuck on this error:

***Error formatting volume Error erasing device.  Error opening device /dev/loop2 for erase: Device or resource busy (udisks-error-quark,0)***

```
lsblk 

Filesystem          Type     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs            devtmpfs      4096       0      4096   0% /dev
tmpfs               tmpfs      1884144       0   1884144   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               tmpfs       753660   10104    743556   2% /run
/dev/mapper/live-rw ext4       7712908 6269868   1426656  82% /
tmpfs               tmpfs      1884144       8   1884136   1% /tmp
vartmp              tmpfs      1884144       0   1884144   0% /var/tmp
tmpfs               tmpfs       376828    3780    373048   2% /run/user/1000

df -T
```